# Using anchors in Wordpress menu creates selection box around content

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

Working with WordPress, I have created a one page site that uses anchors in a custom menu to jump to specific parts of the page.

It jumps to the section of the page that I have specified, as intended. However, it is creating a very visible, blue selection box around the content that it is jumping to. I have not included code in the CSS file or any project files that should be adding a selection box. So my assumption is that it is being caused by Wordpress?

Is there a way to disable a selection box around the content that is being jumped to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is you are getting the outline property add around your selection this happens on chrome alot when you click buttons or focus on something. Try adding a class similar to this

```
SELECTION:focus {outline:0;}
```

to the object that is being highlighted or anchortag without seeing the code and what it is doing its hard to pinpoint the exact class

Comment: Just went ahead and gave this a shot. Worked like a charm, thank you!